# Sendgrid: Send email with template

Tags: email, sendgrid

I am trying to send emails with SendGrid and am trying to have multiple templates for different cases. My function looks like this:

```
var file = "welcome.html"

sendgrid.send({
    to:      to,
    from:     from,
    subject:  subject,
    data: {
        //template vars go here
        email: to,
        confirmLink: confirmLink
    },
    template: "./" + file
}, function(err, json) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
        console.log(json);
});
```

But when I am sending the email I get

```
[Error: Missing email body]
```

Would there be any way to attach html templates, since I don't want to have hard-coded strings with html content?

**Edit**

Reading and converting the file into a string works, but I am unsure how to pass in dynamic variables into the template..

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should really consider using a third-party templating service, such as sendwithus.com or even customer.io. Their API makes it much easier to pass dynamic variables into templates. Bonus - you don't have to parse/render HTML yourself.

Comment: I found that sendgrid do have developed a Templating engine. I have also dug into the source and found a solution. I will post it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for following up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked into the source code and there is a way to pass in dynamic variables.

**welcome.html**

```
<p>Welcome %email%</p>
```

**email.js**

```
var file = "welcome.html"
var stringTemplate = fs.readFileSync("./" + file, "utf8");

//create new Emaik object
var email = new sendgrid.Email();

email.addTo(to);
email.setFrom(from);
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setHtml(stringTemplate); //pass in the string template we read from disk
email.addSubstitution("%email%", to); //sub. variables

sendgrid.send(email, function(err, res){
  //handle callbacks here
});
```

Comment: In this case, the email html is on disk, however sendgrid allows you to create a template through their web UI, how can we leverage those templates?

Comment: I guess they should have documentation about it. The following link might help, although I haven't used their templating system myself: https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Templates/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the template to string. Try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stringTemplate = fs.readFileSync("welcome.html", "utf8");
```

and then:

```
sendgrid.send({
 ...

template: stringTemplate })
```